# "Divide error -Overflow" error in 8086 emu

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

**Write an assembly language program to add all the elements of a table which are between 50 and 100 only. Display the result as the decimal value.**

My soln:

```
.model small 
.stack 64
.data
    table db 0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200 
    ten db 10
.code
    main proc
        mov dx, @data
        mov ds, ax
        lea si, table
        mov dx, 0
        mov bx, 0
        mov cx, 9
    l2: mov ax, [si]   
        cmp ax,   50
        jb l1
        cmp ax, 150
        ja l1
        add ax, dx
        mov dx, ax
    l1: inc si
        loop l2
    l3: mov dx, 0
        div ten
        add dx, 30H
        push dx
        inc bx
        cmp ax, 0
        jne l3
        mov ah, 02H
    l4: pop dx
        int 21h
        dec bx
        jnz l4 
        mov ax, 4c00H
        int 21H
    main endp 
end main
```

It's showing an error -->> **divide error - overflow.to manually process this error,change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.**

What's the solution for this.
**Thanks!**

Comment: Your table is bytes but you load words.

Comment: @Jester okay I changed db to dw for both data. Its displaying 0 as output, why?

Answer (score 4):

> divide error - overflow.**to manually process this error,change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table**.

Very remarkable that emu8086 would make such a suggestion right away!
The solution is to **avoid division error** (an error that you get because the quotient of the division couldn't fit in the destined register `AL`)!
The byte sized division `div ten` that you use, operates on `AX` and leaves the quotient in `AL` and the remainder in `AH`.

Some errors (might) contribute to the problem:

- You're loading words from a table filled with bytes (`mov ax, [si]`).
- You're allowing for a bigger dividend than what the task stated (`cmp ax, 150`).

---

This will work:

```
    xor  dx, dx
    mov  cx, 9
l2: mov  al, [si]
    mov  ah, 0
    cmp  al, 50
    jb   l1
    cmp  al, 100
    ja   l1
    add  dx, ax
l1: inc  si
    loop l2

; At the end of the previous loop, `CX` is zero.
; We can use that for a digit counter instead of `BX`.
; Next division scheme will work fine for dividends up to 2550.

    mov  ax, dx     ; -> AX = 50 + 75 + 100 = 225
l3: div  ten        ; AX / 10  -> Quotient is in AL
    add  ah, 30h    ; Remainder is in AH
    push ax
    inc  cx
    mov  ah, 0
    cmp  al, 0
    jne  l3

l4: pop  dx
    mov  dl, dh
    mov  ah, 02h    ; DOS.PrintChar
    int  21h
    dec  cx
    jnz  l4
```

Comment: @SachinBhusal You can keep the `db` byte data. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!